# CI/CD Pipeline: Failed to pull image with policy: "never"

Tags: gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd, docker-image

Our CI/CD Pipeline stopped being successfull out of the blue.
In our project we were trying to implement the deployment, when suddendly the first test failed and never worked again.

Here is our pipeline:

```html
stages:
  - install
  - build
  - test
  - sonarqube

  - deploy

install:
  stage: install
  tags:
    - nodejs
    - npm
  script:
    - npm install package.json

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - nodejs
    - npm
  script:
    - npm build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - kms-todo/dist/ng-todo/

sonarqube:
  stage: sonarqube
  tags:
    - sonarqube
  variables:
    GIT_DEPTH: "0"
  script:
    - sonar-scanner -D"sonar.projectKey=kms-todo-2023" -Dsonar.login=f7ed6a1b43851b7af315758cb25fe1318fcf1aa4 -Dsonar.host.url=https://scm.thm.de/sonar
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - master

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - nodejs
  script:
    - npm install -g gh-pages
    - ls -lR
    - gh-pages -d kms-todo/dist/ng-todo
  dependencies:
    - build

# unittest-job:
#   stage: test
#   tags:
#     - nodejs
#     - npm
#   script:
#     - npm run test

# job 1/2:
# stage: toPDF
# needs: []
# tags:
#   - nodejs
# script:
#   - makepdf
# artifacts:
#   expire_in: 1 week
#   paths:
#     - "todoList/todoList.pdf"
# when: on_success

# job 2/2:
#   stage: toPDF1
#   script:
#     - echo "PDF1"
```

This is the error we encounter to that encounter:
[image]

We haven't made any alterations to the installation test.
Unfortunately, there isn't much assistance available on Google, so I'm attempting to find a solution here.I am also relatively new to CI/CD and hope that I haven't overlooked any critical details that describes the problem. Tell me if you need more information.

Comment: Are u using ur own runner? If so check the pull policy. Think its set as never. Since its never it wont pull the nodejs image.

Comment: i use the shared runners of GitLab